# Python Tkinter box moving upon re-drawing

Tags: python, tkinter, game-physics

I have a program that re-draws a Tkinter canvas by destroying it and then drawing it again. However, every time that it draws the box, it moves a few pixels over to the right of the screen. For example, if the first box is drawn flush to the left side of the screen, ten or so draws later, it is now flush to the right side of the screen. What is causing this and how can I stop it?

Please note that I am running this all on a Mac, and I have had trouble with things that should work in Tkinter that don't, so if you know that's the issue, please tell me. Thanks for any help and if you need any additional info feel free to ask for it!

After following Bryan Oakley's recommendation, I no longer have the frame being destroyed, only the rectangles. However, now I have the issue that the frame is drawn and remains empty forever... I don't see why.

Code:
    I changed a bit to fit Bryan Oakley's recommendation. Now I get the error `TclError: invalid command name ".4332933704"` at `w.create_rectangle(x, y, z, a, fill="white")`

```
def printBoard(time,board):
    global w
    global root
    x=20
    y=15
    z=60
    a=45
    for i in range(len(board)-3,-1,-1):
        y+=30
        a+=30
        x=20
        z=60
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            x+=40
            z+=40
            if len(board[i][j])==0:    
                w.create_rectangle(x, y, z, a, fill="white")
            else:
                w.create_rectangle(x, y, z, a, fill='black')
    root.after(int(time*1000),tech)

def tech():
    global w
    w.delete(ALL)

def output(board,difficulty):
    global root
    global w
    root=Tk()
    root.lift()
    root.title('Tetris')
    w = Canvas(root, width=500, height=750)
    w.bind_all('<Up>',rotate)
    w.bind_all('<Left>',left)
    w.bind_all('<Right>',right)
    w.bind_all('<Escape>',stop)
    w.pack()
    mainloop()
    global playing
    playing=True
    printBoard(sec,board)
    while playing:
        play(board)
        printBoard(sec,board)
```

Comment: There is no way we can say what bug is causing this behavior unless you show us your code. The Tkinter canvas is rock solid, so the problem almost certainly lies in your code.

Comment: @ChaosPhoenix7 I think The error you describe now may occur if the Canvas `w` does not exist. This would occur if your program ever calls `printBoard` prior to `output`. (You could check this by adding `print` statements.)

Comment: @ChaosPhoenix7 I'm also confused by the code *after* `mainloop()`. You won't get to this until after the tkinter window is closed. Was it a mistake pasting the code?

Comment: @garycomtois I moved the `mainloop()`. I don't know why I put it where I did. My program initializes the frame and makes it successfully to the `create_rectangle`, but fails to actually create the rectangle. I'm getting the error I posted above. And `printBoard` is not called before `output`.

Comment: @ChaosPhoenix7 I see an error. `w.pack` should be `w.pack()`. Does this change your result?

Comment: It does change the result, but not for the better. What used to be an empty frame now appears as a white "glitch" box, and I have to force-quit out of IDLE.

Comment: @ChaosPhoenix7 Well it seems as though your first problem has been solved. You're probably better off asking a new question rather than continuing to edit this one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this answer after a set of edits to your original code. The only way to fix your code is to completely rewrite it, and that's not what this forum is for.

I suggest you stop working on your program and work through a couple tutorials on Tkinter ([tkdocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html) and [pythonware](http://www.pythonware.com/library/index.htm) are good places to start). You have a fundamental misunderstanding of event driven programming. For example, you have code after you call `mainloop`, but calling `mainloop` needs to be the last logical line of code in your program. It is the fact you are trying to create widgets after `mainloop` exits that is causing the latest error (TclError: invalid command name ".4332933704")

Second, you have an infinite loop in your program. Event driven programs already have an infinite loop in the form of the event loop. That is what `mainloop` is. Having your own infinite loop is simply the wrong way to do things. Your program needs to be based on events, not a hard-coded infinite loop.

If you want to trigger a redraw every N milliseconds you can use the `after` tkinter method to schedule a function to be called in the future. If that function does the same thing (ie: calling itself sometime in the future) you've built-in a simple animation loop. For example:

```
class MyApp(...):
    def __init__(...):
        # call it the first time; it will then call 
        # itself several times a second
        self.redraw()

    def redraw(self, *args):
        <redraw everything>
        self.after(42, self.redraw)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you are reinitializing ne whole GUI on each iteration. Tkinter wan't designed to work that way. Doing so will Will yield unpredictable results. You should create exactly one instance of `Tk`! and call `mainloop` exactly once.

The fact the "box" is moving over each time is probably related to that, if by "box" you mean the window. Some windw manager do tnis each time a window is created if you don't specify a location.

Also, it's very unusual to delete and recreate widget -- at tbe very least it's slow and inefficient. There are canvas commands to move objects, or if you really need to you can delete and recreate canvas items.